# When and why use anonymous class instead of stucts for simple objects

Tags: class, struct, c#-3.0, anonymous

I read in this answer [A generic list of anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612689/a-generic-list-of-anonymous-class) how to load a list with anonymous class objects. My question is why and when is recommendable to use this way instead of using a struct, considering performance and good practices.

Comment: I've found two places where I use them often - Linq projections inside a single method, and returning JSON data from an Ajax MVC action.  Oh almost forgot - It's very common use anon classes in MVC Html helper route dictionaries. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should anonymous types be used in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668/how-should-anonymous-types-be-used-in-c), and [other-than-for-linq-queries-how-do-you-use-anonymous-types-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168150/other-than-for-linq-queries-how-do-you-use-anonymous-types-in-c?lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exposed-field structure is essentially a group of variables bound together with duct tape.  It won't behave as an "object", and may thus be seen as evil who think *everything* should behave like an object; nonetheless, in cases where one doesn't really *want* an object, but rather a group of variables bound together with duct tape, an exposed-field structure may be a perfect fit.

Anonymous classes have only a few advantages over exposed-field structures:

- The syntax to declare them is at least slightly smaller; depending upon coding standards, it may be a lot smaller.  If coding standards will allow one to write `internal struct WeightAndVolume { public double weight, volume;}` and say that the struct is "self-explanatory" [it contains two public fields of type `double`, named `weight` and `volume`, each of which will hold whatever was last written to it by outside code], anonymous classes won't save much, but if coding standards would require that every named data type have many pages of associated documentation, including an analysis of required unit-test procedures, anonymous classes could avoid such hassle.
- Copying class references is slightly cheaper than copying structures larger than 8 bytes, though unless a reference would be copied many times, the cost of creating the object will outweigh any savings in copying.
- Casting an anonymous class to `Object` is *much* cheaper than casting a struct.  The first time an anonymous class instance gets cast to `Object` will make up for the extra costs of creating it.  Every additional time will represent a savings of that amount.
- Passing a structure to a generic method will require the JITter to produce a specialized version of the code for that type; by contrast, the JITter would only have to produce one piece of code to handle all anonymous classes.

In general, structures will work better than anonymous classes.  On the other hand, there are a few scenarios (mostly related to the third point above) where classes can end up being much better.

Comment: I agree that struct don't behave or don't have all the necessary to behave as an object, however it is mentioned in [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx) "A class or struct declaration is like a blueprint that is used to create instances or objects at run time". I do appreciate the details about anonymous classes, there is a lot I didn't know and they seem to be quite handy in some cases, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it is ever *recommended* to use anonymous classes, in the sense that it's never wrong to not use them. But they typically get used when

1. it's an one-shot job, for which creating a proper named type would be cumbersome, **and**
2. the consumer of the objects is either compiler-generated code (you don't have access to the types backing those anonymous classes, but the compiler does) or uses reflection (in which case you don't need access to the types at compile time)

The most common scenario where this occurs is in LINQ queries.