# What are anonymous types in C#?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should anonymous types be used in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668/how-should-anonymous-types-be-used-in-c)

What are anonymous types in C#, and when should they be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668/how-should-anonymous-types-be-used-in-c

Comment: I didn't find the answers to that question to be very helpful to me.

Comment: You really have to specify your question more then that page answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous types are types created on the fly typically in order to return results in a LINQ statement. Here's an example from MSDN

```
var productQuery = 
    from prod in products
    select new { prod.Color, prod.Price };
```

A new type with the read-only properties Color and Price is created and the query returns instances of this type when enumerated.

```
foreach(var product in productQuery) {
    Console.WriteLine(product.Color);
}
```

`product` will be of the anonymous type defined above.

Anonymous types are useful for returning several properties from a query without having to define a type explicitly for that purpose.

Comment: You could also just go: var product = new { Color = "Red", Price = 42m }
That is, it doesn't have to be in a LINQ statement.

Comment: @Steffen: I know, but the OP wanted to know when to use anonymous types. In my experience LINQ is the obvious use case.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the horse's mouth: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx