# Finding specific key which has highest value from Dictionary<int, List<int>> with lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, lambda, .net-3.5

I have a dictionary like so -

```vb
public static Dictionary<int, List<int>> pegMap = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
```

Now I have populated the dictionary like say -

```vb
Key: 1 => Value: [3,2]
Key: 2 => Value: []
Key: 3 => Value: [6,7]
```

Now I want to find the key which has the highest value in the list.

Like in this case the the lambda should return `3` which denotes the key-value pair where key is `3` because the number 7 is present in the list in the dictionary where key happens to be `3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bit hacky but should work.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

    dict.Add(1, new List<int>() { 1, 2 });
    dict.Add(2, new List<int>() { 4, 5 });
    dict.Add(3, new List<int>() { 1, 7 });

    var max = dict.Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Value = x.Value.Max() }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First().Key;  
// returns 3
        // Other sample input 
        dict.Add(1, new List<int>() { 1, 2 });
        dict.Add(2, new List<int>() { 4, 7 });
        dict.Add(3, new List<int>() { 1, 2 });
        // returns 2
        dict.Add(1, new List<int>() { 1, 2 });
        dict.Add(2, new List<int>() { 4, 7 });
        dict.Add(3, new List<int>() { 1, 7 });
        // returns 2
        dict.Add(1, new List<int>() { 1,10 });
        dict.Add(2, new List<int>() { 4, 7 });
        dict.Add(3, new List<int>() { 1, 7 });
        // returns 1
```

Edit: to the smallest value in the list with the largest value:

```
 var min_value_in_maxList = dict.Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, ValueMax = x.Value.Max(), ValueMin = x.Value.Min() }).OrderByDescending(x => x.ValueMax).First().ValueMin;
```

Comment: Can you explain the new keyword in the lambda. I'm not getting that part.

Comment: In this case, new generates an anonymous type with two properties, Key and Value. See this question for a detailed answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668/how-should-anonymous-types-be-used-in-c

Comment: Just one more question what if I want to find the least number in the `List<int?>` where max is present.

Comment: See my edit. Just add another anyonymous variable and query that one in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's nothing built into LINQ to Objects which makes this particularly pleasant. You can use [`MaxBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) from my [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) project though, with the slight trick of needing to use `Max` on each list as well:

```
var maxKey = pegMap.MaxBy(x => x.Value.Max())
                   .Key;
```

Note that if there are multiple keys which have the same top element in the list, it will return the first one.

Answer (score 1):

this should work,

```
pegMap.SelectMany(a => a.Value, (a, b) => new {holdKey = a.Key,listValue= b}).OrderByDescending(a=>a.listValue).First().holdKey;
```

Comment: :( , sorry almost same as @Alex answer. Didnt refresh before answering

Comment: Not a problem. I think this is something that [so] should think about. A lot of people, including me, don't refresh before answering or commenting. A real-time problem.