# Real World Example for Anonymous Types of C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I am learning **Anonymous Type** in C#, I have understood how they are defined and used. Below is a sample code I have tried for Anonymous Type.

```
var myType = new {
Name = "Yasser",
City = "Mumbai"
};
Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Type: {1}", myType.Name, myType.City);
```

**My Question**

Where in real world scenario, will these be used ? Can anyone give me an example or scenario where these Anonymous Type could be used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should anonymous types be used in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668/how-should-anonymous-types-be-used-in-c)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

LINQ queries use them a lot:

```
var productQuery = 
    from prod in products
    select new { prod.Color, prod.Price };
```

The `{ prod.Color, prod.Price }` is an anonymous type that has a read-only `Color` and `Price` property. If you would iterate through the results of that query you could use that type as any other class:

```
foreach (var v in productQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Color={0}, Price={1}", v.Color, v.Price);
}
```

In other words, you didn't have to define a new class that would look something like this:

```
public class ColoredPricedItem
{
    public Color {get;}
    public Price {get;}
}
```

Even more, `Color` and `Price` types are correctly inferred from your query.

Answer (score 5):

Lets say you have this kind of class:

```
class User
{
    public int ID;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public int Age;
    public string City;
    public string Country;
}
```

and you creatw a generic list where T is User class. You create n number of users. 
The point is, that you dont want to show all the fields (or properties) in some query, but only firstname + lastname (as one) of a person and a city that person lives.
So you use a new keyword in Linq (i will show how to use don notation of Linq):

```
        List<User> users = new List<User>();
        users.Add(new User { ID = 1, FirstName = "first 1", LastName = "last 1", Age = 32, City = "City 1", Country = "Country 1" });
        users.Add(new User { ID = 2, FirstName = "first 2", LastName = "last 2", Age = 33, City = "City 2", Country = "Country 2" });
        users.Add(new User { ID = 3, FirstName = "first 3", LastName = "last 3", Age = 34, City = "City 3", Country = "Country 3" });

        var query = users.Select(s => new
            {
                FIRST_LAST = string.Format("{0} {1}", s.FirstName, s.LastName),
                LIVING_IN = s.City
            }).ToList();
        foreach (var person in query)
        {
            string name = person.FIRST_LAST;
            string city = person.LIVING_IN;
        }
```

Hope it helps,
bye

Answer (score 3):

As well as being using in Linq they are used by asp.net MVC applications
in Global.asax.cs mapping the routes

```
  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

Some web frameworks use them to represent HTML tag attributes:

```
var t = new Table(new { align="left", bgcolor="red", cellpadding="2" });
```

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous types were added in C# 3 for LINQ. They are great when you only want a few properties from the database e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx:

```
var productQuery = 
    from prod in products
    select new { prod.Color, prod.Price };

foreach (var v in productQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Color={0}, Price={1}", v.Color, v.Price);
}
```

This would only fetch the columns Color and Price from the database :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use it to generate html elements.

The below example uses the method "el" to generate html elements with the given attributes and innerHTML. the parameter "params object[] objects" allows to give any number of anonymous objects to define the desired html attributes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
namespace anonymousTypes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            el("td", null, new { colspan = 36 }, new { style = "text-align: center;" });
            Console.Read();
        }

        static string el(string tagName, string innerHTML, params object[] objects)
        {
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            b.Append("<").Append(tagName);
            foreach (object obj in objects)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    Console.Write(propertyInfo.Name + " | " + propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) + "\n");
                }
            }
            b.Append(">");
            if (innerHTML != null)
                b.Append(innerHTML);
            b.Append("</").Append(tagName).Append(">");
            return b.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```