# Access anonymous object property from static class c#

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, anonymous-objects

I have a static class with multiple anonymous objects. Each object, has a different amount of properties, but each property is always a object of created class.

```
static public class Fields{
    static public Object FieldInfo1 = new {
        Customer = new FieldInformation("value1","value2")        
    } 

    static public Object FieldInfo2 = new {
        Customer = new FieldInformation("value1","value2"),
        Company = new FieldInformation("value1","value2"),        
    } 
}
```

I try to access `Fields.FieldInfo1.Customer` in second class (Program.cs, its a console application) but it isn't working, I only get `Fields.FieldInfo1.` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: .net is a type safe language so your code needs to be type aware, you can't access a property on a variable of type `object` because object does not contain a property called `FieldInfo1`. Anonymous types are probably a bad idea here, what are you trying to do and why?

Comment: It will never work since Fields.FieldInfo1 does not contain a Company property, only Customer.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft sorry my bad, I mean Customer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast it to the type of the object. Because you have non (at compile time) cast `as dynamic`:

```
var obj = Fields.FieldInfo1 as dynamic;
var value = obj.Customer.Prop1; // "value1"
```

But I don't see why you need to do it this way. This is not C# like, which is a strongly typed language. In my opinion you should rethink your design.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668/how-should-anonymous-types-be-used-in-c) might give you a starting point for when it is right to use anonymous types

Comment: @Jauch - I executed it before posting and it doesn't. (I did have to create a `FieldInformation` class with a `Prop1`,`Prop2` for the original code in the question to work)

Comment: Sorry @Gilad, I realized my mistake. I tried to use the "Prop1", but in my code I used other name :)

Comment: @Jauch - No problem :)

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I should really rethink my design.

Comment: @dev.Manderson - maybe having it as a dictionary will be better. And better still in my opinion will be not to have it as static but just pass it to your classes than need it ( look up dependency injection)

Comment: Marked as answered & and yes, I will go with a dictionary. Thanks again!