# Is there a way to define classes inline upon their usage?

Tags: c#, json

I'm writing a service to retrieve data from an API over HTTP from another team in my company. The JSON response body from their API looks a bit like this:

```
"SomeObject": {
    "SomeInnerObject": {
        "SomeProperty": {
            "Id": "123",
            "Type": "abc",
            "Name": "some value"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm writing a C# class to store the data in memory in order to do some comparisons. The nesting of the JSON object causes the class to look annoyingly repetitive:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public SomeObjectModel SomeObject { get; set; }
    public class SomeObjectModel
    {
        public SomeInnerObjectModel InnerObject { get; set; }
        public class SomeInnerObjectModel
        {
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

I know for sure that the inner classes, like "SomeObjectModel", are only going to be read from and not instantiated elsewhere, so is there a way to combine the class definition and property definition lines into something more like this?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public SomeObject { get; set; } :
    {
        public SomeInnerObject { get; set; } :
        {
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The JSON will have arrays in it, so take that into account if you are proposing an alternative using generics, etc.

Comment: Note that the classes declarations themselves don't need to be nested in order to use them in a nested manner.   You could declare the `SomeInnerObject` class at the same level as `SomeObject` but still use `SomeInnerObject` inside `SomeObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, C# does not support any version of that syntactic sugar. The closest thing in C# is probably either anonymous types or value tuples.

Other languages have similar features:

- C++ supports "inline classes" in declarations.
- Java supports anonymous classes that are more sophisticated than C# anonymous record types.
- Scala supports case classes which declare their members in the header of the declaration.

And so on. I think the first is the closest thing to what you are looking for.

Scala-style class declarations have been proposed for C# many times in the last decade, and may finally make it into C# 8; see https://blog.cdemi.io/whats-coming-in-c-8-0-records/

Answer (score 7):

If you're using this just to deserialize the JSON, you don't even need to define a class.. You can use a nested [anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668/how-should-anonymous-types-be-used-in-c).

First, create and populate (with dummy values) an anonymous type that has the properties you need to be able to read. Then pass it as the second parameter to `DeserializeAnonymousType<T>(string,T)`.

The result is a new instance of the same anonymous type that you created, but now it's populated with values from the JSON.

```
var json = @"{'SomeObject': {'SomeInnerObject': {'SomeProperty': {'Id': '123','Type': 'abc','Name': 'some value'}}}}";

var template = new
{
    SomeObject = new
    {
        SomeInnerObject = new 
        { 
            SomeProperty = new 
            {
               Id = default(int),
               Type = default(string),
               Name = default(string)
            }
        }
    }
};

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, template);
var id = result.SomeObject.SomeInnerObject.SomeProperty.Id;
var type = result.SomeObject.SomeInnerObject.SomeProperty.Type;
var name = result.SomeObject.SomeInnerObject.SomeProperty.Name;

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", id, type, name);
```

Output:

```
123 abc some value
```

See my [working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MqJWC7).

Edit: If your JSON contains an array, you can use `new[] {}` to create an array based on type inference and then put the anonymous types inside, like this:

```
var json = @"{ 'SomeObjects': [ { 'Id': '123', 'Name': 'some value' }, { 'Id': '456', 'Name': 'another value' } ]}";

var template = new
{
    SomeObjects = new [] { new { Id=default(int), Name=default(string)} }
};
```

Comment: I would've preferred it to be a class definition, but I'm not hardstruck on it and I imagine this might be my best option.

Comment: How would I create the template with JSON like this?

    "SomeObjects": [
        {
            "Id": "123",
            "Name": "some value"
        },
        {
            "Id": "456",
            "Name": "another value"
        },
    ]

Comment: I updated my answer and the DotNetFiddle example to demonstrate how to handle that sort of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dynamic type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic). Here is a minimal example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("[{key: '1001', value: 'test'}, {key: '1002', value: 'test2'}, ]");
            Console.WriteLine(x[0].key);
            Console.WriteLine(x[0].value);
            Console.WriteLine(x[1].key);
            Console.WriteLine(x[1].value);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a dynamic object, I'd like it to be explicitly typed.

Comment: A class is static by definition (as in "static typing"), so you cannot build a class on-the-fly. The purpose of `dynamic` is to address requirements just like yours.

Comment: Right, so I'm essentially asking for a non-static class that is explicitly typed, which I'm getting the feeling does not exist.

Comment: @Werns Correct. Because if you think about it, the type must be available at compilation for type-checking. The alternative is to use [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples).

Answer (score 0):

You can create classes by using the paste special, paste JSON as classes.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Store-Developer-Solutions/Quckly-Generate-C-Classes-from-JSON-Responses#time=01m56s

Comment: Very cool to know in the future, but currently the JSON from the external API is 2-3 times larger than the data I need, so it'd take more time to cut out what I don't need than to just make what I do need.